# How o activate relationship to add new column in table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I got few tables in PowerBI.

I just want make new add columns to sessions table with mentors region.
But realtionship between **users_mentor** and **regions** not activated.
I can solve this problem by activating relationship between this tables, but I'll have same problem for **mentees** table.

[image]

So I'm trying to solve my problem by this code (I making new table, don't be mad about it, I just trying to understand how it works):

```
sessions_new_table = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    sessions,
    "region", 
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('regions'[name]), 
        USERELATIONSHIP('users_mentor'[region_id], regions[id])
    ))
```

And I get obviously incorrect result, cause one mentor can have only one region:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?